# Where necessary AddIns folder located?

Tags: c#, add-in, visual-studio-addins, autodesk-inventor

I want to create my first add-in program for inventor using c#. I got stuck on a part where i should copy my .addin file to folder AddIns or Inventor AddIns, because i haven't any of these. Not in directory like this **C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Inventor 2014\Addins**   not in **C:\Users\Public\Documents\Autodesk\Inventor 20xx\Inventor Addins** or smth like that.

I've found folder AddIns in directory **C:\Users\Public\Documents\Autodesk\Inventor 2016\SDK\DeveloperTools\Samples\VCSharp.NET\Addins**. That's OK? Because. there are 3 diffrent folders AddIns with diffrent languages. Instead of **VCSharp.NET**  .**.\Samples\VB.NET\Addins** and  **..\Samples\VC++\AddIns**.

Is that AddIns folder what i need?

Thanks for any help =)

P.S. Sorry for my bad English))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
**%AppData%\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProjectName\**
Where "ProjectName" is the name of your project.

**%AppData%\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\**
Should exist whereas you have to make the folder ProjectName

The inside ProjectName Folder you will copy:
**ProjectName.dll

Autodesk.ProjectName.Inventor.addin**